# Gatsby + Netlify-Dev Lambda Functions - Lambda Server Port always different?

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, gatsby, netlify, toml

I am trying to use `netlify-dev` and their serverless functions with my gatsby project.

Here is my `netlify.toml` file

```
[build]
  functions = "lambda"
  command = "gatsby build"
[dev]
  command = "gatsby develop"
  functionsPort = 34567
  port = 8000
  publish = "public"
  targetPort = 8000
```

I added this to my Gatsby Config

```
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware")
module.exports = {
  developMiddleware: app => {
    app.use(
      "/.netlify/functions/",
      proxy({
        target: "http://localhost:34567",
        pathRewrite: {
          "/.netlify/functions/": "",
        },
      })
    )
  },
  //...
```

However, there seems to be something wrong with the port
I always get a new random port, everytime I run `netlify dev`

```
Netlify Dev ◈
◈ Injected build setting env var:  CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME
◈ Injected build setting env var:  CLOUDINARY_API_KEY
◈ Injected build setting env var:  CLOUDINARY_SECRET
◈ Starting Netlify Dev with gatsby
Waiting for localhost:8000.
◈ Lambda server is listening on 61271 //*** I would expect this to be 34567? ***
success open and validate gatsby-configs - 0.066s
⠋ load plugins
```

What am I missing here? And why is the port always different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite you are setting port `8000`, it won't be able to use it because it's already being used by `gatsby develop`. That's why it always gives you a different port number. If you want the port number to be always the same, use another random number (8888 is used by default if you don't set a port).

About your netlify functions, unless you want to set a different port for any particular reason, I would leave them as they are and simply call them by using: `/.netlify/functions/your-function-name`.

I mostly use this minimum configuration on my `netlify.toml`

```
[build]
functions = "functions"
```

Then, in your code, you don't need to worry about port numbers.

**UPDATE**
This seems to be a problem with latest `netlify-cli` release. There is an `issue` already [open](https://github.com/netlify/cli/issues/659).
Rolling back to a previous version seems to be a good temporary solution.

Comment: the port number thats always different is the one for the `netlify functions server `though - not the gatsby server. I am not trying to set the `netlify functions server` to port `8000` (where gatsby is running). Also, I've just changed that port and its still giving me random port numbers for the netlify server? I'm not sure I understand!

Comment: Even if I completely remove the `[dev]` script, and just use a minimal configuration my port number keeps changing.

Comment: Netlify, by default, will use the same por for everything. Both site and functions. When using netlify, you shouldn't access your site with `https://localhost:8000` like you do when you run `gatsby develop`. Instead, you should access it with the port number it generates (usually, the tab that's opened automatically once it finishes starting the process). If you use that tab, you shouldn't care about `serverless` port number because it will use the same one. About port being random, check if you don't have anything already running in port 8888 because that's the one it tries to use by default.

Comment: Another option would be to set a completely different port. `port = 8123`, for instance. It's not a commonly used number for servers and apps so it shouldn't be generating random ports if you do it.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks. There is nothing running on port `8888`. Also, Netlify CLI does not open up anything. In the terminal, gatsby logs `Success!` and then some dots are being added, indicating some sort of loading. It takes forever though.

Comment: Tried it with a totally different port `8123` - doesnt work still.

Comment: In any case, did you try by simply using `/.netlify/functions/your-function-name` ? without setting any proxy? That's how I use it in all my projects (despite lambda server initializes on a different port each time - different that apps port even -) and it works perfectly.

Comment: Wait, I think it's a problem with last `netlify-cli` update. It was working perfectly for me and I just updated to its last version and them same problem you describe (keeps loading) started to happen. Strange.

Comment: I can access `/.netlify/functions/your-function-name` if I use the random port specified. I cannot access the path with just port `8000` (or wherever gatsby is running). I just created a new project to test this out, but it keeps on loading as well. Interesting you have the same error. Damn. :/

Comment: Thank you! That seems to be the same issue! Though I just tried rolling back to 2.11.13, and it's not helping.

Comment: I rolled back to 2.11.12, and this seems to be working better for me. Not 100% sure though.

Comment: It's working now. I also removed all the stuff about ports and am using a minimal config like you said. I don't even need the `http-proxy-middleware` & rerouting in gatsby it seems? Also, if you want to submit something as an answer I'd pick that.